# Composite function (State the domain)

Tags: functions

The function $f$ and the composite function $g\circ f$ are defined by $f(x)=3x^2+2,x\in \mathbb R$ and $g\circ f(x)=9x^4+9x^2+2,x\in \mathbb R$ respectively. Find the function $g$ and state the domain.

My attempt, 
$g\circ f(x)=9x^4+9x^2+2$

$g(3x^2+2)=9x^4+9x^2+2$

Let $u=3x^2+2$

$x^2=\frac{u-2}{3}$

$g(u)=9(\frac{u-2}{3})^2+9(\frac{u-2}{3})+2$

$=u^2-u$

So, $g(x)=x^2-x$.

Am I correct? How to find domain then?

Comment: you can easily check if you are correct by doing the composition $g(f(x))$ and observing if the result is $g(f(x))=9x^4 + 9x^2 +2$. On the other hand, de domain is defined as the possible values of $x$ in which $g$ can be "evaluated". In this case, the domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$ since $g$ is perfectly defined for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $x^2-x$ is $\mathbb R$, since you can insert any value.

To get $g(x)$, simply consider $f(x)^2=9x^4+12x^2+4=9x^4+9x^2+2+3x^2+2=g\circ f(x)+f(x)$

Comment: I want to find domain. Not range.